# Visible div conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a difficult scenario and searched for almost not working consistencly.

My code concept:  I have to append and prepend the "Visible li"
Initial stage of my code:

Html:

```
<div class="img_list" id="slider1"> 
    <a href="#" class="control_next">Nexts</a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev">Prevs</a>

    <ul>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="colors_changes colors-21" style="display:none"></li>
        <li class="colors_changes colors-21" style="display:none"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

> function moveLeft() {
>         jQuery('#slider1 ul').animate({
>               left: + slideWidth
>           }, 200, function () {
>             jQuery('#slider1 ul .active:last-child').prependTo('#slider1 ul');
>               jQuery('#slider1 ul').css('left', '');
>           });
>       };
>
> ```
> function moveRight() {
>   jQuery('#slider1 ul').animate({
>           bottom: - slideHeight
>     }, 200, function () {
>       jQuery('#slider1 ul .active:first-child').appendTo('#slider1 ul');
>       jQuery('#slider1 ul').css('top', '');
>     });
> };
>
> jQuery('a.control_prev').click(function () {
>     moveLeft();
> });
>
> jQuery('a.control_next').click(function () {
>     moveRight();
> });
> ```

Problem starts here when i perform these actions code becomes like the
below code

```
<div class="img_list" id="slider1"> 
    <a href="#" class="control_next">Nexts</a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev">Prevs</a>

    <ul>
        <li class="colors_changes colors-21" style="display:none"></li>
        <li class="colors_changes colors-21" style="display:none"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
        <li class="default-images active"></li>
    </ul>
```

In this condition two li with style display: none occurs, When I click on next active or           visible classes are not working.

I have tried the following jQuery codes

> ```
>    1.:not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"]):last-child or 
>           :not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"]):first-child
>    2. :visible:last-child or  :visible:first-child
> instead of jQuery('#slider1 ul .active:last-child') and jQuery('#slider1 ul .active:first-child').
> ```

li is not prepending and appending when display:none comes as a intermediate.
Need Help.
Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: Your `:not` and `:visible` selectors go inside the jQuery argument, not before it. E.g `$('#slider1 ul .active:visible')`